# Executar um arquivo.js

Tags: javascript, ubuntu

Estou fazendo um curso de JS e criei um arquivo.js em `var/www/html/js/index.js`. Mas quando tento rodar o arquivo no navegador `http://localhost/js/index.js` ele não executa ! Apenas mostra o código que eu escrevi no navegador.

Este é o meu arquivo:

```
function Person() {
    this.name = '';
    this.age = '';
    this.eyesColor = '';
    this.body = '';

    this.move = function() {
        //
    }

    this.say = function() {
        //      
    }

    this.see = function() {
        //      
    }

}

var lucas = new Person();

console.log(typeof Person());
console.log(typeof lucas);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acessar diretamente um arquivo Javascript (.js) não faz com que ele seja executado. Você pode criar uma página HTML e incluir o caminho do seu script.

Ex:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Você também pode executar direto no console do navegador, tecla <kbd>F12</kbd> no Chrome.

Também é possível adicionar diretamente na página, basta criar a tag `<script>` e por o conteúdo dentro dela. Ex:

```
<script>
function Person() {
    this.name = '';
    this.age = '';
    this.eyesColor = '';
    this.body = '';

    this.move = function() {
        //
    }

    this.say = function() {
        //      
    }

    this.see = function() {
        //      
    }

}

var lucas = new Person();

console.log(typeof Person());
console.log(typeof lucas);
</script>
```